# Symfony 2 - shared vendor directory doesn't work with assetic

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I make symlinks to `vendor` directory located outside application directories, and everything works good, but no assetic bundle.

```
www
 |- project1
 |- project2
 |- projectx
 |- vendor
```

When I add in config.yml:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        main_css:
            inputs:
                - @AppBundle/Foundation/stylesheets/app.css
```

It doesn't work: `"Unable to find file "@AppBundle/Foundation/stylesheets/app.css"."`

But if changed to:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        main_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Foundation/stylesheets/app.css
```

It works again. The same happens with twig templates:

```
{% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Foundation/stylesheets/app.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

It doesn't work.

Even if I'm not using symbolic links, but only changing loader path in `app/autoloader.php`, it doesn't work.

What can be done to make it work?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html Don't you have a problem with registered bundles ? Also, I'm not sure if the inputs configuration accepts the @MyBundle/.../ format for paths. Also, for your stylesheets block in Twig, are you sure that it's the right path ? Isn't it @AppBundle/Resources/... ?

Comment: I'm 100% sure it's right path, because when vendor directory is on the right place that path works. Inputs config accepts @Bundle/ as described in manual - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#using-named-assets